# How do you sync a host and container directory with Dockerode?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-volume

How do I sync a folder on my container with a directory on the host so that I can delete the container and make it again with the same data. This is my code so far.

```
let containerMeta = {
    Image: 'secret/image',
    AttachStdout: true,
    AttachStderr: true,
    Tty: true,
    ExposedPorts: {
      '19132/udp': {},
    },
    HostConfig: {
      PortBindings: {
        '19132/udp': [
          {
            HostPort: SERVER_PORT,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  };

let container = await docker.createContainer(containerMeta);
```

I have viewed the documentation and their is not much about this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HostConfig`'s option `Binds`:

```
var Docker = require('dockerode');

var docker = new Docker({
  socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'
});

docker.createContainer({
  Image: 'ubuntu',
  Cmd: ['/bin/ls', '/stuff'],
  'Volumes': {
    '/stuff': {}
  },
  'HostConfig': {
    'Binds': ['/tmp:/stuff']
  }
}, function(err, container) {
  container.attach({
    stream: true,
    stdout: true,
    stderr: true,
    tty: true
  }, function(err, stream) {
    stream.pipe(process.stdout);

    container.start(function(err, data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

You can read more information in Docker Engine API docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/ContainerCreate

And the example I copied, in `dockerode`'s examples: https://github.com/apocas/dockerode/blob/master/examples/external_volume.js

Comment: Can you clarify, so the /stuff (on the container) is the same as /tmp? Can I do this without a directory pre-made on the host?

Comment: Yes, it binds a volume to your container, this can either be a host directory (like the `/tmp` folder in my example) or a volume name. It can either be `host-src:container-dest` or `volume-name:container-dest`. You can see more information in the Docker Engine documentation for Binds in the link I posted above.